# Web api object is null when using data contract with a xml namespace

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to integrate legacy API calls into a new web API project.  The old calls all used data contracts with data members.  I think I have everything matched up but my objects always come in null.  If I remove the namespace from the calls when I try it in fiddler it works.  However, I can't modify the calls coming in.

Here is the controller code.  In this code projectTaskImportBatch comes in as null.

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("ProjectTaskImportBatch")]
public IHttpActionResult BatchImportXltProjectTask(ProjectTaskImportBatch projectTaskImportBatch)
{
   try
   {
      var xltProjectTaks = XltProjectCore.BatchImportXltProjectTask(projectTaskImportBatch, Token);
      return Ok(xltProjectTaks);
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      throw ExceptionHandler.ResponseException(Request, ex);
   }
}
```

And this is the object I'm attempting to populate.

```
 [DataContract(Namespace = "http://col4.com/api/v2", Name = "ProjectTaskImportBatch")]
 public class ProjectTaskImportBatch
 {
    [DataMember(Order = 1)]
    public string ProjectID { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Order = 2)]
    public string Tasks { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Order = 3)]
    public Int16 LastBatch { get; set; }
}
```

This is the call I'm making from Fiddler.  If I remove  xmlns="http://col4.com/api/v2"  the code works.  However that is not an option.

```
POST http://localhost: HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Content-Type: application/xml;
Accept-Language: en-US
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; Trident/7.0; .NET4.0E; .NET4.0C; InfoPath.3)
Host: localhost:
Content-Length: 261
Connection: Keep-Alive
Pragma: no-cache
Authorization:

<ProjectTaskImportBatch xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://col4.com/api/v2">
<ProjectID>(Project ID here)</ProjectID>
<Tasks>1|Testing Namespace||||||||||</Tasks>
<LastBatch>1</LastBatch>
</ProjectTaskImportBatch>
```

Edited - Added info:

I think I found the problem.  I put this code in my  `Global.asax`
`GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter.UseXmlSerializer = true;`

This makes everything else work great, but it breaks all of the calls with `DataContracts`.  If I set `UseXmlSerializer = false;` it works but everything else breaks.

Is there a way to set it to false for only the legacy parts, or is there an all around better way to do this?

Comment: Based on your above information, everything looks fine...can you check for model state in your action to see if there are any errors: `if (!ModelState.IsValid){ return BadRequest(ModelState); }`

Comment: @KiranChalla I put that in my controller correct?  When I did the response was "Bad Request".  However, I removed the   xmlns="http://col4.com/api/v2" from the call and tried again.  Then it passed the ModelState check without an error.

Comment: `ModelState` should have been serialized and this would have error information...you can probably use tools like `Fiddler` to see what the errors look like...

Comment: @KiranChalla  I just looked in Fiddler and under text view this is the Error is gave me.'<Error><Message>The request is invalid.</Message><ModelState><projectTaskImportBatch>There is an error in XML document (1, 108).</projectTaskImportBatch></ModelState></Error>'

Comment: hmm...that message is not that clear...how are you crafting the message...manually or is some serializer doing it?

Comment: @KiranChalla I'm going to say some serializer is doing it.  I put the model state code in ran the call from Fiddler and found that in the 
"TextView" in the response.  Sorry I'm just learning this stuff and probably barely have my head above water at this point.